# binding date related data with grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

Grid View Data Bind

i have a database table with 4 columns having data type Date.
I want to bind this database table with a grid view but the problem is grid view take these columns as DateTime and displays date and time in the grid view.
please can any one help me.
I want only date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out below

<columns>

<asp:BoundField headertext="CreationDate" dataformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" 
       datafield="CreationDate"  HtmlEncode="false" />

<asp:BoundField headertext="UpdationDate" dataformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" 
       datafield="UpdationDate" HtmlEncode="false" />

</columns>

Comment: thank you its working but now when i click on the edit linkbutton it again shows date with time for updating.

Comment: I think it would be better to convert BoundField to TemplateField you can follow this link doing this http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs